# MySQL replication - database size is different

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

I have enabled MySQL master-master replication with 2nd master acting as read-only. Recently I checked the out the size of the databases in both master and slave and I found that database size in two databases is 1mb less than the Master. Does it mean that the setup which I made for master-slave was not done properly or the replication is not happening properly?
Also, how can I make the changes so that it remains the same in both master and slave?

Thanks!

Comment: 1mb out of 2mb?  or 1mb out of 9999mb?

Comment: MyISAM?  or InnoDB?

Comment: Statement based replication?  Or Row?

Comment: Innodb and statement based. Master is 150mb and slave is 151mb.

Comment: naschoff's answer and most of its comments apply.  Less than 1% difference is rather small.  SBR (vs RBR) probably makes differences slightly more common.

Comment: MySQL Replication Checker Tool works like charm

Answer (score 3):

The setup can differ slightly in size and be consistent at the same time. Could be a range of reasons for the size difference. E.g. Different file system, fragmentation, method of determining size, etc...

If you want to test the consistency of your replicated tables, run a pt-table-checksum.

Comment: But I have replicated everything.. pt-table-checksum will be able to help me resolve it? since file system is the same in both. Ideally when you have master and a slave, the databases size should be the same right?

Comment: @tesla747 No, the replication works with the data, not the files in the system. If you for instance do some inserts in one transaction and then do a rollback (maybe because there was an error), the data get written and then removed on the first server, but nothing is replicated to the other one. Your data are perfectly in sync, but the way they are stored differs a bit.

Comment: so you mean to say, the database size being different is totally fine? it isnt convincing.. how can I confirm this technically? FYI, I run SELECT table_schema "DB Name", Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY table_schema;  -----> to find the database size

Comment: Tesla747, As both jkavalik and I have said. This is totally fine. I've seen masters with twice the size on disk due to fragmentation. Your method of determining consistency by comparing data size is flawed and will not be able to detect this. Check the DATA_FREE field in the information_schema.tables table. You'll probably see that the "larger" one has a higher number here. But, by all means test the true data consistency by verifying the checksums through the use of Percona's pt-table-checksum tool. It will run a data level consistency check which will give you a true comparison of your data.

Comment: @tesla747 or if you want to "see yourself" - just do a full dump of two versions of some not so big table with the different reported sizes and do a diff - all rows should be the same unless there is some reordering (and that should not happen if you have primary keys properly defined, but even if it did, you will be able to match the positions by hand). de-synchronization *can* happen in some case if you use some unsafe construct and statements, but the file size is not the way to detect it and moreover the numbers from `information_schema` are *approximations only* afaik.

Comment: ok let me run pt table checksum.. its safe to run it in production right?

Comment: @jkavalik approximations indeed.

Comment: @tesla747, go on to Percona.com and read the documentation published for this tool. It is vital, to properly use it and to safely asses (mitigate) potential risks involved in running the tool. I'd advise to thoroughly research and test any and everything you plan to use in your prod environment.

Comment: alright.. but what is the precise way to find the database sizes then?

Comment: @tesla747 "database size" is not an exact number, when database is used(updated) the size always changes (or in some older cases entire partition was allocated to it, no files existed at all). Active database contains some empty space so it can be faster, because perfectly managing it would be slow. And the "pattern" of this empty space can change with some operations or just their order. So you just cannot have the "size of this database" precisely to a single byte unless it is stopped/offline. For finding how much space you need (for backup etc), just check filesystem and add a safe margin.

Comment: @tesla747 , I agree with jkavalik. Size is a loose term when it comes to databases. It depends on what you're looking for. For resource planning or binary backups, you can safely use the table space size in the file system.  I.e. (du -sh /opt/mysql/data/*). For row counts, a count(*) or use database; show table status; (approx.)

Comment: Guys now when I check.. The slave size of one of the databases is one mb higher than the master.. This has to be wrong right?

Comment: @tesla747 Did you check the consistency through one of the methods described above?

Answer (score 1):

If you can pause both the master & slave and do:

> REPAIR TABLE tablename;

on both the master and the slave you may find they are now the same size.

There is probably a better way to do the repair that would not pause a production server, but this work for me while testing.
I plan to do this on a live production environment so will update if successful.

**Update:**
Just realised you don't need to pause anything. Just issue "REPAIR TABLE tablename;" on Master and the slave will do the same automatically once the master has completed the repair.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer...  **MVCC** involves keeping 'old' copies of rows around even after new ones exist (due to `UPDATE`) or have been `DELETEd`.  This is so the the "transaction isolation" characteristics can be followed.  Also "undo" values are kept until transactions are `COMMITted`.  Both of these inflate InnoDB datasets with extra data that may not be fully squeezed out over time.

Keeping an extra copy of a row around may necessitate a "**block split**", wherein a 16KB block is split into two such blocks.  After the extra copy is purged, the two blocks may not be rejoined, thereby leading to the table being 1 block bigger.

Any attempt (sort of doing a hex dump of the data) to see this extra record or extra block will work.  InnoDB will report exactly the set of rows that are currently 'visible', and not show you these other records.

Meanwhile `SHOW TABLE STATUS` will show you the exact size of the "data" and "index".  Note that each number is a multiple of 16K.

Comment: The "old" copies for mvcc and "undo values" you are referring to are one and the same thing. They are kept in the undo slots of the rollback segment. The records have hidden ids pointing to them. Depending on iso lvl, other transactions and dml type, they're sometimes kept for longer than the commit. As the "old" row is kept in the rollback segment and not the idb table space file, I don't see how this can make any difference in this case. Ps. Doesn't the data_length represent bytes, not pages?